# In T-SQL, how can I create a new partition every time I hit a certain criteria, and keep that partition until the next time I see that criteria?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here's the output I'm hoping to achieve:

[image: Output]

I'd like to start with the most recent ReportMonth working backwards and start a new partition every time there's a MonthsBetween > 2. I'd like to avoid loops if possible.

EDIT: Here's the create statement for the table

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    MonthsBetween int,
    ReportMonth date)

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(0, '2019-12-01')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(1, '2019-11-01')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(1, '2019-10-01')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(3, '2019-07-01')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(1, '2019-06-01')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(3, '2019-03-01')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your MonthsBetween uses a Lag or Lead function already(or precalculated)

```
create table #temp (
MonthsBetween int null,
ReportMonth date null
)

insert into #temp (MonthsBetween,ReportMonth)
Values ('0','2019-12-01'),
('1','2019-11-01'),
('1','2019-10-01'),
('3','2019-07-01'),
('1','2019-06-01'),
('3','2019-03-01')


select t.*,
sum(case when MonthsBetween <= 2 then 0 else 1 end) over (order by t.[ReportMonth] DESC) +1  as [PartitionID]
from #temp t
```

Answer (score 4):

You may try with the following approach using `LAG()` and windowed `SUM()`:

Statement (for groups based on difference between each two values for `MonthsBetween` > 2):

```
SELECT
    MonthsBetween,
    ReportMonth, 
    SUM(GroupID) OVER (ORDER BY ReportMonth DESC) AS PartitionID
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        CASE 
            WHEN LAG(MonthsBetween) OVER (ORDER BY ReportMonth DESC) IS NULL THEN 1
            WHEN MonthsBetween - LAG(MonthsBetween) OVER (ORDER BY ReportMonth DESC) >= 2 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS GroupId
    FROM #temp
) cte
```

Statement (for groups based on value for `MonthsBetween` > 2):

```
SELECT 
   MonthsBetween,
   ReportMonth,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MonthsBetween > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY ReportMonth DESC) + 1 AS PartitionID
FROM #temp
```

Result:

```
MonthsBetween   ReportMonth PartitionID
0               2019-12-01  1
1               2019-11-01  1
1               2019-10-01  1
3               2019-07-01  2
1               2019-06-01  2
3               2019-03-01  3
```